# Creating new ad in existing ad set does not work

Tags: advertising, facebook

When I try to "Create a similar ad" on Facebook, there is the option to choose an existing ad set in which to publish the ad. But these settings are never updated on the ad creation page, and all ads I create also create a new ad set.

**How do I create a new ad within an existing ad set?**

I tried the power editor in Google Chrome, but every new ad was rejected even before upload for not complying to something Instagram, even if it was an exact duplicate of an existing (accepted and active) ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked fine the next morning. I guess the problem was that these functions rely on Javascript, and dynamic JavaScript functionality often fails without error (here in Germany) when the USA wake up and Facebook gets really busy. So if you have a similar problem, try when America sleeps. Solved the problem for me.